# What is stuck on chipboard to give wood appearance in flatpack furniture?

Tags: finishing, chipboard

I have discovered that all the desks I own are chipboard. However, on the surface they look like real wood. I conclude that something has been stuck on the suface using glue to give this impression and this something is think like paper and it is certainly not actual wood.

What is stuck on chipboard to give impression of real wood? Where can I buy this material and stick it on projects I make myself using chipboard?

Comment: Or you could use plywood for your projects. It already looks like wood, since *it is* wood. It's only slightly more expensive than chipboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a plastic veneer. Often referred to by the name "[Melamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melamine_resin)" (probably even when it isn't actually melamine).

Some laminates may be white melamine with a wood grain pattern printed on it, others may be other plastic materials with a wood grain printed on it.

You can buy sheets of melamine at many big-box home improvement stores or, likely, at smaller woodworking specialty stores or lumber yard. At those specialty stores, you might also consider buying real wood veneer which you could also adhere to your chipboard to make it look like real wood (because you would actually have a thin layer of real wood on it).

If you go for real wood veneers, you could purchase them in many different species (online retailers may have a larger selection than your local store, but your local lumber yard will probably be more than happy to help you select the species that you like the best and to order some in for you if they don't have it in stock.

Additionally, by using real wood veneer, you have your choice of how to finish it, using different colored stains as desired, and a variety of different top coats from shellac to polyurethane, depending on your desires and the use case for each individual piece.

Comment: From what I've seen the "melamine" surface is always a lamination, built around Kraft paper. While you do get a pseudo-wood texture imprinted into some melamine laminate, the wood effect is generally simply printed on paper underneath the melamine top coat.